# PHP fputcsv different columns

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, fputcsv

I am exporting data into csv i have multiple arrays that i want to add to csv file. I am able to insert data into csv for first array.

What i want i want to put 2nd array data parallel to first array data.

example csv:

```
Array1:               Array2:       Array3:
1 2 3 4               a b c d       xd xy cd
5 6 7 8               e f g h       dg dy cs
```

Code:

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w+');


  foreach ($ofdPerCompany as $row){

    $array = array( $row->company_name, $row->countofwaybill);
    fputcsv($output, $array); // here you can change delimiter/enclosure
}

    // tell the browser it's going to be a csv file
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    // tell the browser we want to save it instead of displaying it
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv";');

  fclose($output);
```

Can anyone help me how i can split csv into different columns.

Comment: Did you try array_merge()?

Comment: I have separate arrays with different number of records.

Answer (score 1):

If you have three arrays with a varying number of records you can do the following:

```
$first = [];
$second = [];
$third = [];

// Get maximum size
$maxLength = max(count($first), count($second), count($third));

// Write headers manually
fputcsv($fh, ["First", "Second", "Third"]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $maxLength; $i++) {
  // If key does not exist use empty string
  $data = [
    $first[$i] ?? "",
    $second[$i] ?? "",
    $third[$i] ?? ""
  ];

  fputcsv($fh, $data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try.